# How to solve $y'(x)=(y+2)^{1.5}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this DE: $y'(x)=(y+2)^{1.5}$

First I got $\int \frac{1}{(y+2)^{1.5}} dy=\int 1 dx$

Then I got $\frac{-2}{(y+2)^{0.5}}=x+c$

Then I solved for $y$

$\frac {x}{-2}+c=\frac{1}{(y+2)^{0.5}}$

$\frac {x^2}{4}+c=\frac{1}{(y+2)}$

$y+2=\frac {4}{x^2}+c$

$y=\frac {4}{x^2}-2 $

BUT when I try to plug in my work, I do not get a correct answer:

$(\frac {4}{x^2}-2 +2)^{1.5}=\frac {8}{x^3}$ is not equal to $y'(x)=\frac {-8}{x^3}$

I know that my answer is wrong based on this, I would appreciate it if someone solved the problem or pointed out my mistake.

Comment: $(\frac{x}{-2}+c)^2 \neq \frac{x^2}{4}+\tilde{c}$ for any choice of the constant $\tilde{c}$. Similarly, $(\frac{x^2}{4}+c)^{-1} \neq \frac{4}{x^2}+\tilde{c}$.

Comment: When you square, the LHS is $(\frac{x}{-2}+c)^2=\frac{x^2}{4}+c_1 x +c_2$

Comment: @jawheele you are right, my error is definitely in that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a+b)^p \neq a^p+b^p$. You made this error twice, first with squaring ($p=2$), and then with taking the reciprocal ($p=-1$). Also, from a stylistic point of view, $(y+2)^{-1.5}$ tends to be easier to work with than $\frac 1 {{(y+2)}^{1.5}}$